# How to work with tables in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a sort of general question but i think that if I tried to be too specific I would only make it very confusing. So basically what I want to know is this:

When you create a table in Corona/Lua you can put pretty much an unlimited number of things in it correct?

So say i create a table called

```
   rectangles = {};
```

and then i put a bunch of instances of rectangles in it. If i wanted to change a property of ALL the rectangles at once, how could I do it?

I understand how it would work with a set number of items in the table, like:

```
    for i = 1, 10 do 
        rectangles[i] = display.newImage("rectangle.png");
```

then to change all of the images x positions for instance you would simply say

```
     rectangles[i].x = 20;
```

but how would you change a property of all items in the array without knowing how many there are, as in you didnt give an upper bound, and cant because the table is always growing?

Comment: -1: for lack of research. How to iterate over all the elements of a list in Lua is basic stuff you could find anywhere. It doesn't matter if it's a list of Corona objects; a list is a list.

Comment: You may consider tweaking your question a bit, it may mislead other people to downvote you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For arrays that have only one kind of elements you can use `#rectangles` for element count.

```
for i = 1, #rectangles do 
        rectangles[i] = display.newImage("rectangle.png");
end
```

---

Regarding the [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abfaLoUw0ss) example,

if you add element into `rectangles` like this:

`rectangles[b]=b;`

what it actually does is

`rectangles["083DF6B0"]=b"`

you see when a display object `b` is used as a key it is converted into a hex string.

in addition, you would need to use `pairs` to go over each element as they are
keys (e.g. array.length,array.width,array.weight..) rather than index (e.g. array[2],array[3]..)

```
for key,value in pairs(rectangles) do
    print(key); --prints 083DF6B0
    print(value); --prints 20
    rectangles[key]=30;
end
```

Comment: I do know that #rectangle would mean the entire length of the table, but the problem is that I was watching this tutorial here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abfaLoUw0ss

and at about 33:50 he does this balloons[b] = b which I do not understand, and then says you cant use # this way. But if i try to call on all of the elements in the table using balloons[b], to for instance change the x value of all the elements. (balloon[b].x = 10). it does not work

Comment: @Steve Patterson - the youtube example is storing by key versus by index. If you're doing the same, you'll want to iterate over each item in the table using [pairs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs).

Comment: @Corbin March - Thanks for the info, I must admit though the Lua Reference is a bit confusing seeing as I am new to programming. So if I was trying to do a transition.to() to all of the items in this table, what would I put as the first argument? transition.to(what would i put here?, {time, x, y});

Comment: @Steve Patterson - as I understand [transition.to](http://developer.anscamobile.com/node/2407), you need to call it once for each item you want to animate - in your example, each item in your rectangles table. Something like `for index,value in ipairs(rectangles) do transition.to(value,{time,x,y}) end` (use `pairs` if storing by key). I'm not a Corona developer, however, so this is just what I gather from the docs. Don't hesitate to throw a new question out there. Good luck.

Comment: @StevePatterson answer edited. For the rest Corbin March already have a good answer

Comment: @Corbin March and cctan - Thanks so much for the help and the patience. I finally got it working properly.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you're storing items in the table. If you're storing by index (as in your example), you can use [ipairs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) to iterate over indexes and values:

```
for index,value in ipairs(rectangles) do
    value.x = 20
    --or
    rectangles[index].x = 20
end
```

If you're storing by key (as in the youtube video you mention in a comment), iterate using [pairs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs):

```
for key,value in pairs(rectangles) do
    value.x = 20
    --or
    rectangles[key].x = 20
end
```

Just don't store items using both index and keys, unless you know what to expect.